# It is throwing an IO Exception when I am trying to overwrite a file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms

I have a windows forms app to export payslip details, it asks the user to select a month and division and after that the user has an option to Export All the fields or Export only selected fields. When the user clicks Export or Export All button it opens a Save File Dialog Box with the file name being payslip_SelectedDesignation_SelectedMonth. When the user selects save it creates a new excel file saves it in the selected location then mails the exported file. Now when I click on Export or Export All the first time it is overwriting the file but when I click the button a second time it is showing The process cannot access the file D:\PaySlip Recruitment Aug2023.xlsx because it is being used by another process.  The code is working just fine if I remove the code to send the saved Excel File as attachment. But I definetly need to send that mail!!!

This is for Export All button

```
`private void btnExportAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
     Workbook workbook = null;
     Worksheet worksheet = null;
     try
     {
         //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application 
         excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
         workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
         worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1] as Worksheet;

         DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value;
         //string month = date.ToString("MMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         string selectedValue = cmbYear.Text;
         DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(selectedValue, "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         string month = parsedDate.ToString("MMMyyyy");

         if (boolyearChanged == true && boolMonthChanged == false)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Month", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             return;
         }

         string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRWEBAPPConn"].ConnectionString;
         string selectedDivision = cmbDivision.Text;
         string queryString = "Select TOP 20 [Serial No], Month, Division, EmployeeID, [Employee Name], Designation, DOJ, PAN, [PF No], UAN, [Pay Period], [Pay Days], LOP, SL, CL, EL, Basic, HRA, Conveyance, Medical, [Personal Allowance], [Special Allowance], [OverTime Allowance], [Shift Allowance], Bonus, Basic_YTD, HRA_YTD, Conveyance_YTD, Medical_YTD, [Personal Allowance_YTD], [Special Allowance_YTD], [OverTime Allowance_YTD], [Shift Allowance_YTD], Bonus_YTD, [Income Tax], [Provident Fund], [Professional Tax], [Bonus Deduction], [Misc Deduction], [Income Tax_YTD], [Provident Fund_YTD], [Professional Tax_YTD], [Bonus Deduction_YTD], [Misc Deduction_YTD], [Gross Earnings], [Gross Earnings_YTD], [Gross Deductions], [Gross Deductions_YTD], [Bank Name], [IFSC Code], [Account No], [Income Tax Balance], [Professional Tax Balance], EEPF, EEVPF, EREPS, ERPF, EEPF_YTD, EEVPF_YTD, EREPS_YTD, ERPF_YTD, Status, [Created Date], [Created By] from tblPaySlip Where Division = @SelectedDivision AND Month = @Month";

         if (selectedDivision != "IT" && selectedDivision != "Recruitment")
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Division", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             return;
         }

         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             con.Open();
             using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, con))
             {
                 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedDivision", selectedDivision);
                 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);
                 System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                 adapter.Fill(dt);

                 if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                 {
                     string fileName = month;

                     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                     saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
                     saveFileDialog.FileName = "PaySlip_" + selectedDivision + "_" + fileName + ".xlsx";

                     if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                     {
                         string savePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;

                         if (File.Exists(savePath))
                         {
                             DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("The file already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                             if (result == DialogResult.No)
                             {
                                 return; // Cancel the operation if the user chooses not to overwrite
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 // Delete the existing file
                                 File.Delete(savePath);
                             }
                         }

                         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                         {
                             worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                         }

                         for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
                         {
                             decimal decNet_Pay = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[row]["Gross Earnings"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[row]["Gross Deductions"]);
                             for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
                             {
                                 worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 1] = dt.Rows[row][col];
                             }
                             worksheet.Cells[row + 2, dt.Columns.Count + 1] = decNet_Pay;
                             worksheet.Cells[row + 2, dt.Columns.Count + 2] = ConvertRupeesToWords(decNet_Pay);
                         }


                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerRow = worksheet.Rows[1];
                         headerRow.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                         headerRow.Font.Size = 11;
                         headerRow.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
                         headerRow.Font.Name = "Arial";
                         headerRow.Font.Bold = true;

                         for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; row++)
                         {
                             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentRow = worksheet.Rows[row];
                             currentRow.Font.Size = 10;
                             currentRow.Font.Name = "Arial";
                         }

                         #region Column_Names
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Serial No";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Month";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Division";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Employee ID";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Employee Name";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Designation";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 7] = "DOJ";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 8] = "PAN";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 9] = "PF No";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 10] = "UAN";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Pay Period";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Pay Days";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 13] = "LOP";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 14] = "SL";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 15] = "CL";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 16] = "EL";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 17] = "Basic";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 18] = "HRA";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 19] = "Conveyance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 20] = "Medical";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 21] = "Personal Allowance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 22] = "Special Allowance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 23] = "OverTime Allowance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 24] = "Shift Allowance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 25] = "Bonus";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 26] = "Basic_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 27] = "HRA_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 28] = "Conveyance_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 29] = "Medical_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 30] = "Personal Allowance_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 31] = "Special Allowance_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 32] = "OverTime Allowance_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 33] = "Shift Allowance_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 34] = "Bonus_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 35] = "Income Tax";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 36] = "Provident Fund";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 37] = "Professional Tax";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 38] = "Bonus Deduction";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 39] = "Misc Deduction";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 40] = "Income Tax_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 41] = "Provident Fund_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 42] = "Professional Tax_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 43] = "Bonus Deduction_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 44] = "Misc Deduction_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 45] = "Gross Earnings";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 46] = "Gross Earnings_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 47] = "Gross Deductions";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 48] = "Gross Deductions_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 49] = "Bank Name";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 50] = "IFSC Code";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 51] = "Account No";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 52] = "Income Tax Balance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 53] = "Professional Tax Balance";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 54] = "EEPF";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 55] = "EEVPF";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 56] = "EREPS";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 57] = "ERPF";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 58] = "EEPF_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 59] = "EEVPF_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 60] = "EREPS_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 61] = "ERPF_YTD";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 62] = "Status";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 63] = "Created Date";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 64] = "Created By";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 65] = "Net Pay";
                         worksheet.Cells[1, 66] = "Net Pay in Words";
                         #endregion

                         #region Alignment
                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SNoCol = worksheet.Columns[1];
                         SNoCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PayDaysCol = worksheet.Columns[12];
                         PayDaysCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range LOPCol = worksheet.Columns[13];
                         LOPCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SLCol = worksheet.Columns[14];
                         SLCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CLCol = worksheet.Columns[15];
                         CLCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ELCol = worksheet.Columns[16];
                         ELCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range BasicCol = worksheet.Columns[17];
                         BasicCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range HRACol = worksheet.Columns[18];
                         HRACol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ConveyanceCol = worksheet.Columns[19];
                         ConveyanceCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range MedicalCol = worksheet.Columns[20];
                         MedicalCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PACol = worksheet.Columns[21];
                         PACol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SACol = worksheet.Columns[22];
                         SACol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range OACol = worksheet.Columns[23];
                         OACol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ShACol = worksheet.Columns[24];
                         ShACol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range BonusCol = worksheet.Columns[25];
                         BonusCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range BasicYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[26];
                         BasicYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range HRAYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[27];
                         HRAYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ConvYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[28];
                         ConvYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range MedicalYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[29];
                         MedicalYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PAYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[30];
                         PAYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SAYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[31];
                         SAYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range OAYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[32];
                         OAYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ShYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[33];
                         ShYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range BonusYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[34];
                         BonusYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ITCol = worksheet.Columns[35];
                         ITCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PFCol = worksheet.Columns[36];
                         PFCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PTCol = worksheet.Columns[37];
                         PTCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range BDCol = worksheet.Columns[38];
                         BDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range MDCol = worksheet.Columns[39];
                         MDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ITYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[40];
                         ITYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PFYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[41];
                         PFYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PTYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[42];
                         PTYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range BDYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[43];
                         BDYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range MDYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[44];
                         MDYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range GECol = worksheet.Columns[45];
                         GECol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range GEYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[46];
                         GEYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range GDCol = worksheet.Columns[47];
                         GDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range GDYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[48];
                         GDYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ITBCol = worksheet.Columns[52];
                         ITBCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PTBCol = worksheet.Columns[53];
                         PTBCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range EEPFCol = worksheet.Columns[54];
                         EEPFCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range EEVPFCol = worksheet.Columns[55];
                         EEVPFCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range EREPSCol = worksheet.Columns[56];
                         EREPSCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ERPFCol = worksheet.Columns[57];
                         ERPFCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range EEPFYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[58];
                         EEPFYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range EEVPFYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[59];
                         EEVPFYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range EREPSYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[60];
                         EREPSYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ERPFYTDCol = worksheet.Columns[61];
                         ERPFYTDCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range NetPayCol = worksheet.Columns[65];
                         NetPayCol.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                         #endregion

                         //UAN Number Formatting
                         int UANcolumnIndex = 10;

                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range columnRange = worksheet.Columns[UANcolumnIndex];
                         columnRange.NumberFormat = "0";

                         //Columns Total

                         int[] columnsToSum = { 17, 37 };

                         double[] columnTotals = new double[columnsToSum.Length];

                         for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; rowNum++)
                         {
                             foreach (int columnIndex in columnsToSum)
                             {
                                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnIndex];

                                 double cellValue = 0;
                                 if (cell.Value != null && double.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out cellValue))
                                 {
                                     columnTotals[Array.IndexOf(columnsToSum, columnIndex)] += cellValue;
                                 }
                             }
                         }

                         //Total Sum
                         int newRowPosition = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2;
                         worksheet.Rows[newRowPosition].Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);

                         int startingColumnIndex = 1;
                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range totalCell = worksheet.Cells[newRowPosition, startingColumnIndex];
                         totalCell.Value = "Total:";
                         totalCell.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                         totalCell.Font.Bold = true;
                         totalCell.Font.Size = 11;
                         totalCell.Font.Name = "Arial";

                         for (int i = 0; i < columnsToSum.Length; i++)
                         {
                             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentCell = worksheet.Cells[newRowPosition, columnsToSum[i]];
                             currentCell.Value = columnTotals[i];
                             currentCell.Font.Bold = true;
                             currentCell.Font.Size = 11;
                             currentCell.Font.Name = "Arial";
                         }

                         worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                         workbook.SaveAs(savePath);
                         workbook.Close(false);

                         Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);
                         Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);

                         excelApp.Quit();
                         Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);

                         
                         con.Close();

                         // Set the objects to null
                         worksheet = null;
                         workbook = null;
                         excelApp = null;
                         
                         string recipientEmail = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
                         string senderEmail = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
                         string emailSubject = Path.GetFileName(savePath);
                         string emailBody = "Please find attached the PaySlip file.";
                         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailSubject))
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("File saved sucessfully", "Sucess", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                             SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                             smtpClient.Port = 587;
                             smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, "xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx");
                             smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                             MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, recipientEmail, emailSubject, emailBody);
                             Attachment attachment = new Attachment(savePath);
                             mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                             smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                         }
                     }
                     
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show($"{month} doesn't have any Fields", "Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                     workbook.Close();
                     excelApp.Quit();
                     con.Close();


                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         workbook.Close();
         excelApp.Quit();
         con.Close();

     }
     finally
     {
         // Make sure to release resources even in case of an exception
         if (worksheet != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);
         if (workbook != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
         if (excelApp != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
     }
 }
`
```

Comment: If I delete ` if (File.Exists(savePath))` It is showing Can't access'PaySlip Recruitment Aug2023.xlsx'

Comment: Looks like the file is open after you create it. What exactly are you doing after you create the file?

Comment: The way this code is written, Excel and database connections remains open if any error happens. At the very least use `using` blocks for any Excel objects to ensure they're disposed. It's also *very* slow because it makes a cross-process call for every single cell value and property. It's a *lot* easier and faster to use a library like eg EppPlus and load query results into a sheet with `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataRead(results);` or `.LoadFromCollection()`. You can specify styling and headers through extra parameters. The entire code could be reduced to 15 lines without using Excel at all

Comment: I am sending the file as an email attachment @PMF

Comment: I will try and do that, this is my first time handling excel operations, so I may have made some very basic errors . Thank you for the suggestion 
@Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the Interop.Excel for this. Use a library that knows how to read/write excel without needing any excel processes or installs as in-between.

This will make file interactions way more predictable and possibly faster too.

Example of such library is EPPlus